# Combine the name of 2 data frames and assign it ti third in R

Tags: r, string

I have written a function to combine to join 2 dataframes. But the joined file which I am getting should be stored in name format such as "x_city".

```
test<- function(x,m=csv){
  a=as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  b=a[,-c(1)]
  x$long=as.numeric(x$long)
  x$long=round(x$long,5)
  x$lat=as.numeric(x$lat)
  x$lat=round(x$lat,5)
  df_name<-paste()
  name<-paste(x,"city", sep="_")
  name=join(x=x ,y=b, by = c("long","lat"))
}
```

test(abc,m=csv)

So, final data frame should be "abc_city".

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that you have a `data.frame` called, for instance, `abc` and you would like to use `dplyr`'s join to join it onto another `data.frame`, `m`, and give it a new name which is the name of the first `data.frame` (`abc`) followed by '_city'. So in your example you would end up with a `data.frame` called `abc_city`.

So the variables that you create in your function only exist in the scope of the function - the call `test(abc, m = csv)` will print out the value of name `name` if you add a return statement but it won't store it in a variable. In order to store it in a variable called `abc_city` you would use

```
abc_city <- test(abc, m = csv)
```

Building on Chi Pak's answer, you could create a dataframe in the parent frame using:

```
test<- function(x,m=csv){
            nm <-deparse(substitute(x))
            # a=as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
            # b=a[,-c(1)]
            # x$long=as.numeric(x$long)
            # x$long=round(x$long,5)
            # x$lat=as.numeric(x$lat)
            # x$lat=round(x$lat,5)
            assign(paste(nm, "city", sep="_"), join(x=x ,y=b, by = c("long","lat")), envir = parent.frame())
            return(get(paste(x, "city", sep="_")))
        }
```

and call it as in your question

`test(abc, m=csv)`

Comment: It's still not working. Giving following error message: In assign(paste(nm, "city", sep = "_"), join(x = x, y = latlong,  :
  only the first element is used as variable name.

Comment: Try now. After editing the datafame, you can't get the name of it anymore so you have to save it as the first thing you do in the function.